# Cannot invoke 'register' : UITableView in Swift3

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a `UITableViewController` which registers a cell in once it has loaded

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    self.tableView.registerClass(cellClass: UITableViewCell.self,
                                 forCellReuseIdentifier: "test")
}
```

and the corresponding code

```
override tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "test", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = "LABEL"
    return cell
}
```

However, XCode gives me the error

```
Cannot invoke 'registerClass' with an argument list of type
'(cellClass: UITableViewCell.Type, forReusableIdentifier: String);
```

---

Apple's API is

```
func registerClass(_ cellClass: AnyClass?, 
                     forCellReuseIdentifier identifier: String)
```

---

Why do I receive this error?

Comment: The error message is about a `register` method, not `registerClass`. Where exactly does that error occur? Perhaps you have a typo in your source code?

Comment: Ah sorry, that's just a copy-paste error. I've tried both register and registerClass method calls. I've edited to reflect.

Comment: Omit the `cellClass:` label, or just try it with Xcode's autocompletion ...

Comment: @MartinR: You're right - thanks!